# Randomly swapping elements in an array causes it to go to zero when the array is on the stack

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

Here's the relevant code (in C):

```
uint8_t sort_array[SORT_ARRAY_LEN];
for (int i = 0; i < SORT_ARRAY_LEN; i++) {
    sort_array[i] = rand() % 256;
}

// Every frame
int el1_i = rand() % SORT_ARRAY_LEN;
int el2_i = rand() % SORT_ARRAY_LEN;
uint8_t temp = sort_array[el1_i];
sort_array[el1_i] = sort_array[el2_i];
sort_array[el2_i] = temp;
```

When I run this for long enough, elements will seem to disappear over time until every element is zero. I can't figure out why this happens, but after a while of commenting out random things, I've discovered that changing

```
uint8_t sort_array[SORT_ARRAY_LEN];
```

to

```
uint8_t *sort_array = malloc(sizeof(u8) * SORT_ARRAY_LEN);
```

fixes the problem. Why on earth is this happening?

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

#define SORT_ARRAY_LEN 160

#define MAX_TICK_SAMPLES 100

void error_quit(char * message) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s SDL_Error:\n\t%s\n", message, SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
}

void draw_array(SDL_Surface * screen_surface,
                uint8_t * sort_array, int sa_len)
{
    int bar_width = SCREEN_WIDTH / sa_len;
    for (int i = 0; i < sa_len; i++) {
        int bar_height = (SCREEN_HEIGHT * sort_array[i]) / 256;
        SDL_Surface * bar_surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(
            0, bar_width, bar_height, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        SDL_FillRect(bar_surface, 0,
            SDL_MapRGB(bar_surface->format, 255, 0, 0));
        SDL_Rect bar_rect;
        bar_rect.x = i * bar_width;
        bar_rect.w = bar_width;
        bar_rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - bar_height;
        bar_rect.h = bar_height;
        SDL_BlitSurface(bar_surface, 0, screen_surface, &bar_rect);
        SDL_FreeSurface(bar_surface);
    }
}

int main() {
    /* INITIALIZATION */
    SDL_Window * window;
    SDL_Surface * screen_surface;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        error_quit("Trouble initializing.");
    }
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Sorting Visualizer",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    );
    if (window == 0) {
        error_quit("Trouble creating the window.");
    }
    screen_surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    if (screen_surface == 0) {
        error_quit("Trouble getting window surface.");
    }

    srand(time(0));

    uint8_t sort_array[SORT_ARRAY_LEN];
    //uint8_t * sort_array = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * SORT_ARRAY_LEN);
    for (int i = 0; i < SORT_ARRAY_LEN; i++) {
        sort_array[i] = rand() % 256;
    }

    /* FRAMERATE SETUP */
    int tick_index = 0;
    int tick_sum = 0;
    int tick_list[MAX_TICK_SAMPLES];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TICK_SAMPLES; i++) {
        tick_list[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("[ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < SORT_ARRAY_LEN; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", sort_array[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");

    /* MAIN LOOP */
    uint8_t running = 0xFF;
    SDL_Event event;
    while (running) {
        int frame_start_time = SDL_GetTicks();
        /* PROCESS EVENTS */
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = 0x00;
            }
        }
        /* SORTING */
        int el1_i = rand() % SORT_ARRAY_LEN;
        int el2_i = rand() % SORT_ARRAY_LEN;
        uint8_t temp = sort_array[el1_i];
        sort_array[el1_i] = sort_array[el2_i];
        sort_array[el2_i] = temp;
        /* DRAWING */
        SDL_FillRect(
            screen_surface, 0,
            SDL_MapRGB(screen_surface->format, 255, 255, 255)
        );
        draw_array(screen_surface, sort_array, SORT_ARRAY_LEN);
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        /* FRAMERATE */
        int frame_time = SDL_GetTicks() - frame_start_time;
        tick_sum -= tick_list[tick_index];
        tick_sum += frame_time;
        tick_list[tick_index] = frame_time;
        if (tick_index++ == MAX_TICK_SAMPLES) {
            tick_index = 0;
        }
        if (SDL_GetTicks() % 50 == 0) {
            //printf("%f\n", (double)tick_sum / MAX_TICK_SAMPLES);
        }
    }

    /* CLEANUP */
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    printf("[ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < SORT_ARRAY_LEN; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", sort_array[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the function within which `sort_array` is declared ever return?

Comment: All of this is in main() right now.

Comment: Post the complete code for an example that shows the problem.

Comment: Here's the complete code, it requires SDL2 though: https://gist.github.com/pixlark/e4a56196de50cff0b437b0eddcdf3772

Comment: The `tick_index++ == MAX_TICK_SAMPLES` condition appears to by off-by-one, writing to index MAX_TICK_SAMPLES due to the post-increment.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at that, although I'm pretty sure that doesn't have anything to do with the issue.

Comment: @pixlark: well it did... slowly dripping zeroes one at a time into the `sort_array`.

Comment: You may think it has nothing to do with the issue.   It will definitely cause undefined behaviour when `tick_index` is used to access `tick_list[tick_index]`, which suggests it is definitely a relevant factor.  Changing an array to a malloced memory of the same size is a pointer to some OTHER code causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oops I guess it turned out to be the problem all along. This is hilarious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array in defined with automatic storage in the `main` function.  Moving it to the heap should not have an effect.  What you observe count be the side effect of a bug elsewhere in the code that overwrites the array with zero values...

Here it is:

```
if (tick_index++ == MAX_TICK_SAMPLES) {
    tick_index = 0;
}
```

This test is off by one, it should be:

```
if (++tick_index == MAX_TICK_SAMPLES) {
    tick_index = 0;
}
```

This error causes a buffer overfow every `MAX_TICK_SAMPLES+1` runs, possibly storing a `0` into the first entry of the other array, which eventually gets moved randomly to another location in the array.

This is an awesome bug! The array contents are rotting away over time...

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what to say. If I replace the stack allocation with a heap allocation, it works. I'm not changing anything else when I do that.

Comment: Holy cow! Thank you so much, that is an incredible bug.

Comment: @pixlark: yes incredible and with such a cool graphical display... made my day!